# Rails categories, subcategories, items and comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a simple rails program that would help me categorize my items, for example my music and videos:

So I would have main category music and in there rock/folk/house and another category videos with subcategories action/drama/comedy

Plus I want to add items with this fields:

id, title, location, some comments on the item.

I'm pretty new to rails, so I ask for the simplest solution or tips on what to read. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A guide to Rails Active records associations is a good a good place to start:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html